# Type error when using alt.condition for mark point angle

Tags: python, altair

I am trying to plot arrows pointing left or right and being green or red, depending on the condition. It works for the color, but not for the angle of the triangle (mark point) which I'm using for the head of the arrow. Here is the data and code:
[image]

```
color=alt.condition("datum.Current >= datum.Previous",alt.value("green"),alt.value("red"))
angle=alt.condition("datum.Current >= datum.Previous",alt.value(210),alt.value(30))
alt.Chart(df_chart).mark_point(size=200,shape='triangle'
                    ,angle=angle).encode(alt.X('Current'),alt.Y('Group'),color=color)
```

I'm getting this error:
[image]

This is what I get if I change the angle to a number, it works without error, except that I don't get the red arrow pointing to the left:[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass `alt.condition` to the angle encoding rather than the angle mark property:

```python
alt.Chart(df).mark_point(size=400, shape='triangle').encode(
    alt.X('Current'),
    alt.Y('Group'),
    angle=alt.condition("datum.Current >= datum.Previous", alt.value(210), alt.value(30)),
    color='Group:N'
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can't use a conditional as for a `mark` parameter, only for `encoding` parameters as per https://github.com/altair-viz/altair/issues/1976. <s>Now, for some reason, it seems like that conditional does not work when passed to the `angle` encoding either</s> (see Jake's answer for a working solution, I must have had a typo when trying that), but you could work around that by using transform_calculate to compute the new field values and reference that field:

```
alt.Chart(df_chart).mark_point(size=400, shape='triangle').encode(
    alt.X('Current'),
    alt.Y('Group'),
    angle=alt.Angle('angle:Q', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[0, 360])),
    color='Group:N'
).transform_calculate(
    angle="datum.Current >= datum.Previous ? 210 : 30"
)
```

[image]

It is important to define the domain when using an angle value from a field, you can see another example here https://altair-viz.github.io/gallery/wind_vector_map.html?highlight=wind. Generally I would avoid passing a condition to color just to control the values and instead use the `range` parameter with an existing field value as explained in the docs https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/customization.html#color-domain-and-range

Comment: Great solution, thank you, @joelostblom

Comment: @flbyrne See Jake's reply below for a cleaner solution. That is the same as I thought would work myself, but I must have had a typo somewhere. I'll leave my answer here as an alternative approach, but go ahead and accept his.